# jquery - avoid build up of clicks for slider

Tags: jquery, animation, slider

i have a slider, which I want to stop at the last slide (margin-left:-2586px;).

im using the below jquery to animate between each slide on click (currently only going left).

the problem is the slider will go past the -2586px if you click the #left quickly. how can i make sure this doesnt happen?

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    var left = 862;
    if($('#slider-visible').css('margin-left') == '-2586px'){
    }
    else{
        $('#slider-visible').animate({'margin-left':'-=' + left},500);
    }
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the element is in the middle of animation. If it is, don't run the animation again.

```
else{
    if($('#slider-visible:animated').length == 0){
       $('#slider-visible').animate({'margin-left':'-=' + left},500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is this wrong:

```
$('#left').click(function(){
    var left = 862;
    if($('#slider-visible').css('margin-left') == '-2586px'){
    }
    else{
        $('#slider-visible').animate({'margin-left':'-=' + left},500);
    }
});
```

not stopping an animation queue ( using `.stop()` ), and using `-=` and trying to use `==` to detect an exact position.... **wrong**

A correctly built slider has a `.stop()` and a...
**counter** ! 
The animations usually are built depending on:

- the number of elements,
- click = increase (decrase for  the *"previous"* button) the counter
- and the animation like `left: - counter*oneSlideWidth`
- and this simple logic that resets your counter to 0 `counter = counter % numberOfSlides`
- additionally you check if the counter reaches the value of `-1` (inexistant left slide) than you set it to the `numberOfSlides-1` and you do again:

```
 $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -counter * slideWidth });
```

**Basic sliders logic:**

```
var galleryWidth = $('#gallery').width(), 
    counter = 0,
    numberOfSlides = $('#gallery .slides').length;


$('#prev, #next').click(function() {

   if( this.id=='next'){
      counter++;
      counter = counter % numberOfSlides ; // will reset to '0' if both match
   }else{ // prev was clicked
      counter--;
      if(counter==-1){
         counter = numberOfSlides-1 ;
      }
   }

   $('#slider').stop().animate({left: - counter * galleryWidth  }, 700);

});
```

OR simply:

```
$('#prev, #next').click(function() {      
   var myId = this.id=='next' ? counter++ : counter-- ;
   counter = counter===-1? numberOfslides-1 : counter%numberOfSlides;     
   $('#slider').stop().animate({left: - counter * galleryWidth  }, 700);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think if you test this , it will work :
 `var element=$('#left');

 else{
        $('#slider-visible').animate({element.style.marginLeft=left},500);
    }`

Comment: Won't solve as click queue will still build up. Accepted answer works.